# Почему не работает первая функция?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Ошибок не выдает, но при этом реагирует сразу на вторую функцию c выдачей уведомлений, без выдачи `ReplyKeyboard` функции с `markup` из первой. Почему идет обработка сразу второй функции без выдачи информации из первой? Как оформить код с последовательным открытием двух `def`?

```
import time
import schedule
import json
from telebot import types

bot = TOKEN

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def func(message):
    if (message.text == "A"):
     markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
        la = types.KeyboardButton('1')
        lo = types.KeyboardButton('2')
        markup.add(la, lo)
        process.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбор:', reply_markup=markup)


def send_notification():
  
    users = [1111111, 2222222, 3333333]
    for user in bot.get_updates():
        if user.message:
            if user.message.text == '/start':
                users.append(user.message.chat.id)

    
    for user_id in users:
        bot.send_message(user_id, 'Время cделать выбор!')
        time.sleep(15)




schedule.every(2).minutes.do(send_notification)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)



bot.polling( )
```

Comment: "Почему идет обработка сразу второй функции..." Потому что в коде `send_notification` используется в нижней части, а `func`  определена, но нигде не используется... Вы определили, что функции делают, но вызывается в коде только одна (точнее даже передается в `schedule`, который сам уже ее вызывает).